# Pandas: Pairwise concatenation of column vectors

Tags: python, pandas, permutation

I'm working with a frame like

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'G1':[1.00,0.69,0.23,0.22,0.62],
'G2':[0.03,0.41,0.74,0.35,0.62],
'G3':[0.05,0.40,0.15,0.32,0.19],
'G4':[0.30,0.20,0.51,0.70,0.67],
'G5':[0.40,0.36,0.88,0.10,0.19]
})
```

and I want to manipulate it so that the columns are pairwise permutations of the current columns e.g. all columns are now 10 elements long and for example column 'G1:G2' would have column 'G2' appended to column 'G1'. I have attached a mock-up pic. Note that the pic has named indices unlike the above example code. I can work with or without the indices.

How could I approach this? I can make a function to act on each column, but I think the function would have to return a data frame made by concatenation with all other columns. Not sure what that would look like.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way, although I suspect there might also be a way to do this directly in pandas

```
from itertools import permutations

'''Get all the column permutations'''
lst = [x for x in permutations(df.columns, 2)]

'''Create a list of columns names'''
names = [x[0]+'_'+x[1] for x in lst]

'''Create the new arrays by vertically stacking pairs of column values'''
cols = [np.vstack((df[x[0]].values,df[x[1]].values)).ravel() for  x in lst]

'''Create a dictionary with column names as keys and the arrays as values'''
d = dict(zip(names, cols))

'''Create new dataframe from dict'''
df2 = pd.DataFrame(d)

df2

   G1_G2  G1_G3  G1_G4  G1_G5  G2_G1  G2_G3  G2_G4  G2_G5  G3_G1  G3_G2  \
0   1.00   1.00   1.00   1.00   0.03   0.03   0.03   0.03   0.05   0.05   
1   0.69   0.69   0.69   0.69   0.41   0.41   0.41   0.41   0.40   0.40   
2   0.23   0.23   0.23   0.23   0.74   0.74   0.74   0.74   0.15   0.15   
3   0.22   0.22   0.22   0.22   0.35   0.35   0.35   0.35   0.32   0.32   
4   0.62   0.62   0.62   0.62   0.62   0.62   0.62   0.62   0.19   0.19   
5   0.03   0.05   0.30   0.40   1.00   0.05   0.30   0.40   1.00   0.03   
6   0.41   0.40   0.20   0.36   0.69   0.40   0.20   0.36   0.69   0.41   
7   0.74   0.15   0.51   0.88   0.23   0.15   0.51   0.88   0.23   0.74   
8   0.35   0.32   0.70   0.10   0.22   0.32   0.70   0.10   0.22   0.35   
9   0.62   0.19   0.67   0.19   0.62   0.19   0.67   0.19   0.62   0.62
```

This is part of the output

To avoid creating the lists and use the fact that itertools.permutations is a generator:

```
d = dict((x[0]+'_'+x[1] , np.vstack((df[x[0]].values,df[x[1]].values)).ravel())
                      for x in permutations(df.columns, 2))

df2 = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd do it like this

```
from itertools import permutations

l1, l2 = map(list, zip(*permutations(range(len(df.columns)), 2)))

v = df.values
pd.DataFrame(
    np.vstack([v[:, l1], v[:, l2]]),
    list(map('S{}'.format, range(1, len(df) + 1))) * 2,
    df.columns.values[l1] + ':' + df.columns.values[l2]
)
```

[image]

Comment: Good nigth too ;)